Como puedo agregar un tweet en mi editor tiptap?
Estoy utilizando TipTap para mi editor para mi blog, estoy intentando agregar un tweet, si uso un metodo que encontre (aqui), donde se crea una extensión para TipTap utilizando React-Tweet, al estar editando si me muestra el tweet, pero cuando lo renderizo en el apartado publico este solo muestra lo siguiente:
<twitter src="..."></twitter>

Y ya no muestra el contenido.
Por lo que intente usar la opción que proporciona twitter, para compartir o insertar un tweet, al intentar copiar y pegar me da un error y si lo agrego junto al html de la siguiente forma:
onClick={() =>
                        editor
                            .chain()
                            .focus()
                            .setContent(
                                editor.getHTML() +
                                    `<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">...`
                            )
                            .run()
                    }

El resultado es similar a lo siguiente:

¿Ahora aclaro que estoy utilizando tailwind en el CSS, por lo que no sé si es un tema de los estilos, estoy agregándolo mal y existe otra forma de realizarlo o que podría está realizando mal?
